# while using session storage in iframe angular-oauth2-oidc give error of DOMException: Failed to read the 'sessionStorage'

Tags: angular, iframe, session-storage, angular-oauth2-oidc, domexception

I am using the **angular-oauth2-oidc** package for authentication and my application is used in iFrame, so when the third-party cookies are blocked, it will give the below error.

```
core.js:6241 ERROR DOMException: Failed to read the 'sessionStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document.
at Object.createDefaultStorage [as useFactory] (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:81943:5)
at Object.factory (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:30286:28)
at R3Injector.hydrate (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:30153:63)
at R3Injector.get (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:29903:33)
at injectInjectorOnly (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:15722:33)
at Module.ɵɵinject (http://localhost:4200/vendor.js:15732:57)
at **Object.OAuthService_Factory [as factory]**
```

When I removed the session storage from the code, I got the same error message.
My question is angular-oauth-oidc package somehow use the session storage?
How can I overcome this situation except allow the third-party cookies because I can not rely on a person using this solution to allow the third-party cookies?

Answer (score 0):

Yup, restrictions in browsers will do this. If `sessionStorage` is not available to your application the library will not be able to save any tokens in the default storage mechanism.

You need to [create a custom `OAuthStorage`](https://manfredsteyer.github.io/angular-oauth2-oidc/docs/additional-documentation/configure-custom-oauthstorage.html) and create an in-memory implementation or some other implementation that coordinates with the parent frame to ensure data from the library gets persisted.

Custom storage could look like this:

```
export class CustomOAuthStorage {
  private _data: object = { };
  getItem(key: string) { return this._data[key]; }
  setItem(key: string, value: string) { this._data[key] = value; }
  removeItem(key: string) { delete this._data[key]; }
}
```

And then `provide` it through Angular's DI system.